# Woocommerce: Auto-redirect to cart after adding product from category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

http://www.passgotutoring.com/shop/product-category/ucla/ucla-14a/

I am trying to get a auto redirect towards WP_Cart to happen as soon as a client "adds to cart" one of our classes that are located on the left.

Most of my clients buy a product, pay for it right away so I dont need to really have them keep shopping or anything.

I have tried inputting this code in to my function.php of my theme with no luck when I wanted them to go to their checkout directly.

```
add_action('init','woocommerce_go_to_checkout_action',30);
function woocommerce_go_to_checkout_action(){
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) || sizeof($woocommerce->cart->get_cart())==0) )
    return; wp_safe_redirect( $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url() );
}
```

Any ideas on how I could get it to work?
1. I would like it to go to cart instead of checkout. 
2. I tried the `checkbox` method on the catalog page and it did not work.

Comment: Helpful tutorial: https://www.scratchcode.io/how-to-redirect-users-after-add-to-cart/

Answer (score 50):

In WooCommerce `3.x` you'll find this setting under:

**WooCommerce > Settings > Products > General > Add to cart behaviour > [✓] Redirect to the cart page after successful addition**

---

In WooCommerce `2.3` you'll find this setting under:

**WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display > [✓] Redirect to the cart page after successful addition**

---

In WooCommerce `2.1` you'll find this setting under:

**WooCommerce > Settings > Products > [✓] Redirect to the cart page after successful addition**

Comment: What if i need redirect only on specific condition(like product in sale offert) and still to use ajax in the other case?

Comment: In that case, you create a custom redirection function in the `functions.php` file of the child theme that you are using.

Answer (score 6):

try to uncheck this..

WooCommerce > Settings > General > Scripts > [✓] Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on product archives

Comment: It worked, however this option is present in the WooCommerce > Settings > Catalog > Catalog Options

Answer (score 2):

WooCommerce Settings | Catalog |
Catalog options | Add to cart | Please check the "Add to cart Redirect to the cart page after successful addition" option.

Answer (score 1):

In WooCommerce 2.1.8 you´ll find this setting under...
WooCommerce Settings | Products | Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives

Answer (score 1):

In WooCommerce 2.3.11 you'll find this setting under...

**WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display > Add to cart behaviour > [✓] Redirect to the cart page after successful addition**

[Docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/)

Answer (score 1):

Using a filter hook, you can use the following snippet.

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'change_woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect_url');
function change_woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect_url($url){
    $url = wc_get_cart_url();
    return $url;
}
```

The code goes into your child theme or active theme's functions.php file. Tested and working.