# Redirect to cart page after adding product to cart woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

How can i redirect customer to cart page after clicking on add to cart button for variable product?
I am using generatepress theme and https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-variant-table-for-woocommerce/ plugin for table view of product variation.

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Woocommerce: Auto-redirect to cart after adding product from category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295766/woocommerce-auto-redirect-to-cart-after-adding-product-from-category)

Comment: Hi @NishitManjarawala 
Nope, because this is only working for single product & i want redirect to cart page for variable products.

Comment: Contact the plugin author for solution. But default variation is working with woo settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily go to "WooCommerce > configuration > Products" and check "Move to cart after adding to cart" and save the settings.

Comment: Thanks but this works only for single product, i want redirection for variable products.

Comment: ok
try following codes and put them in **functions.php** :

`// define the woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect callback 
    function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect( $wc_get_cart_url ) { 
        // make filter magic happen here... 
        return $wc_get_cart_url; 
    }; 
             
    // add the filter 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 10, 1 );`

Comment: Added, but not working